# How to transfer a csv file from notebook folder to a datastore

Tags: python, azure, file-upload, azure-machine-learning-service, movefile

I want to transfer a generated csv file `test_df.csv` from my Azure ML notebook folder which has a path `/Users/Ankit19.Gupta/test_df.csv` to a datastore which has a web path `https://abc.blob.core.windows.net/azureml/LocalUpload/f3db18b6`. I have written the python code as

```
from azureml.core import Workspace
ws = Workspace.from_config()
datastore = ws.get_default_datastore()
    
datastore.upload_files('/Users/Ankit19.Gupta/test_df.csv',
                  target_path='https://abc.blob.core.windows.net/azureml/LocalUpload/f3db18b6',
                  overwrite=True)
```

But it is showing the following error message:

```
UserErrorException: UserErrorException:
    Message: '/' does not point to a file. Please upload the file to cloud first if running in a cloud notebook.
    InnerException None
    ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UserError",
        "message": "'/' does not point to a file. Please upload the file to cloud first if running in a cloud notebook."
    }
}
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67897947/how-to-transfer-data-from-azure-ml-notebooks-to-a-storage-container) but it is not working for me. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the path was mentioned is not accurate. The datastore path will be different manner.
Replace the below code for the small change in the calling path.

[image]

```
from azureml.core import Workspace
ws = Workspace.from_config()
datastore = ws.get_default_datastore()
    
datastore.upload_files('./Users/foldername/filename.csv',
                  target_path=’your targetfolder',
                  overwrite=True)
```

We need to call all the parent folders before the folder.  **`“./”`** is the way we can call the dataset from datastore.